# grouping/moving nodes with same attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

After reading 5 hours here on stackoverflow and on other websites I was not able to create a solution for my problem. A lot of described problems an solutions sounds familiar with my one. But unfortunatly I was not able to addapt it to me needs.

My initial xml file looks like this:

```
<document>
  <page>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String1" bottom="12" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String2" bottom="12" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String3" bottom="12" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String4" bottom="20" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String5" bottom="20" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String6" bottom="30" />
      </line>
    </block>
  </page>
  <page>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String10" bottom="20" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String11" bottom="20" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String12" bottom="25" />
      </line>
    </block>
  </page>
</document>
```

The result i try to reach with xslt looks like this:

```
<document>
  <page>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String1" bottom="12" />
        <span string="String2" bottom="12" />
        <span string="String3" bottom="12" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String4" bottom="20" />
        <span string="String5" bottom="20" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String6" bottom="30" />
      </line>
    </block>
  </page>
  <page>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String10" bottom="20" />
        <span string="String11" bottom="20" />
      </line>
    </block>
    <block>
      <line>
        <span string="String12" bottom="25" />
      </line>
    </block>
  </page>
</document>
```

Now my thougts in natural speek:

- identify a block element
- compare:

  ```
  following-sibling::*[1]/line/span/@bottom = self::line/span[last()]/@bottom"
  ```
- if equal - copy the `span` from "downstairs" as last node under the actual `block/line` node
- delete the "old" `span` node
- delete the whole sibling, consist only of `//block/line` without any further `span`

And this is one bad try of finding a working xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity - copy all other data-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="//block/line">
      <line>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        <xsl:if test="parent::block/following-sibling::*[1]/line/span/@bottom = span[last()]/@bottom">
            <xsl:copy-of select="parent::block/following-sibling::*[1]/line/span" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::block/following-sibling::*[1]/*" />
        </xsl:if>
      </line>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope anyone can help! :-)

Comment: are you definitely stuck at xslt 1 (as it's a lot simpler with xslt2:-)

Comment: Normaly I use `xmlstarlet` from commandline to translate or test some things. Unfortunatly it does not support xslt2. But it should be no problem to use `xsltproc`, which can handle xslt2. So when someone comes up with a xslt2 solution I will also be pleased. :-)

Comment: xsltproc is xslt1 only

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thx. I musst have something messed up. Now I've searched the web for an command line linux tool. But when you don't like Java, it seems that there is no tool with xslt2 enabled available. Wether libxml2/xslproc nor xmlstarlet seems to plan an integration. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT2 (or 3) you'd use xsl:for-each-group, but in XSLT1 you can do the same with "Muenchian Grouping" (Using a key to avoid the performance cost of checking the siblings at each iteration)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="b" match="page//span" 
     use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::page[1]),' ',@bottom)"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
 <page>
  <xsl:for-each select=".//span[generate-id()=
            generate-id(key('b',
            concat(generate-id(ancestor::page[1]),' ',@bottom))[1])]">
   <block>
    <line>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('b',
                  concat(generate-id(ancestor::page[1]),' ',@bottom))"/>
    </line>
   </block>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </page>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thx David. Your solution works like a charme. Looks like I should warm up with xslt2. :-)

Comment: Ups - would say: Now it's not the time to warm up with xslt2. Seems as I've to go to bed now. ;-)